# Why pagination display out of main section in Firefox by swiper?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, swiper.js

Why pagination display out of main section in Firefox by swiper when i insert some slide large content and some slide short content than that issues come in firefox not a other browser like chrome. i will try i think two bootstrap 4 column height is not working in Firefox also working fine in chrome browser please help me. Thanks in adavance.

seen my attachment image what is issue in Firefox.

Issue slide with short content:[image]

without issues slide with large content: [image]

```js
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
            },
        });
```

```css
.slider-content {
                background-color: #000;
                padding: 10%;
                color: #fff;
            }
            .slider-content h1 {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
            .slider-content p {
                font-size: 18px;
                line-height: 26px;
            }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js'></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="custom-slider">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="swiper-container">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-wrap">
                                <div class="col-md-6 bg-very-dark-purple slider-content">
                                    <h1>What is Slide 01?</h1>
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the prin, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of</p>
                                    <p>Letraset sheets containing desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 position-relative slider-image background-cover" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1000/500');background-size: cover;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-wrap">
                                <div class="col-md-6 bg-very-dark-purple slider-content">
                                    <h1>What is Slide 02?</h1>
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is </p>
                                    <p>Letraset sheets including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 position-relative slider-image background-cover" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1000/500');background-size: cover;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-wrap">
                                <div class="col-md-6 bg-very-dark-purple slider-content">
                                    <h1>What is Slide 03?</h1>
                                    <p>Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 position-relative slider-image background-cover" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1000/500');background-size: cover;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Add Pagination -->
                        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with the content on different slides. first slide has more content than other two. follow these steps.

- remove `padding: 10%` and gave `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to `.slider-content`
- using `flex`, you can adjust the content to center.
- wrap those content in a `div`
- give `min-height` to `.swiper-slide`

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            pagination: {
                el: '.swiper-pagination',
                clickable: true,
            },
        });
```

```css
.slider-content {
                background-color: #000;
                /*padding: 10%;*/
                color: #fff;
                display: flex; /* Added */
                align-items: center;
            }
            .slider-content h1 {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
            .slider-content p {
                font-size: 18px;
                line-height: 26px;
            }
            /* New CSS */
            .swiper-slide {
              min-height: 370px; /* give as per your requirement */
            }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js'></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="custom-slider">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="swiper-container">
                        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-wrap">
                                <div class="col-md-6 bg-very-dark-purple slider-content">
                                <!-- caption wrapper -->
                                    <div>
                                      <h1>What is Slide 01?</h1>
                                      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the prin, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of</p>
                                      <p>Letraset sheets containing desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                    </div>
                                 <!-- caption wrapper ends -->   
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 position-relative slider-image background-cover" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1000/500');background-size: cover;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-wrap">
                                <div class="col-md-6 bg-very-dark-purple slider-content">
                                  <!-- caption wrapper -->
                                    <div>
                                      <h1>What is Slide 02?</h1>
                                      <p>Lorem Ipsum is </p>
                                      <p>Letraset sheets including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                    </div>
                                  <!-- caption wrapper ends -->  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 position-relative slider-image background-cover" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1000/500');background-size: cover;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-wrap">
                                <div class="col-md-6 bg-very-dark-purple slider-content">
                                  <!-- caption wrapper -->
                                    <div>
                                      <h1>What is Slide 03?</h1>
                                      <p>Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
                                    </div>
                                   <!-- caption wrapper ends --> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 position-relative slider-image background-cover" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1000/500');background-size: cover;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Add Pagination -->
                        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0d8bjwyt/)

Comment: @Dharmesh Vekariya please let me know if you need more clarification. hope this will help you.